# Размер динамического массива

Tags: c++

Дан динамический массив. Как узнать его размер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под динамическим массивом подразумевается указатель, инициализированный кодом вида

```
int* array = new int[42];
```

то никак.

В некоторых реализациях размер можно достать вызовом [_msize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc.aspx)/msize/malloc_size, но стандарт это не оговаривает:

```
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int *arr = new int[42];
    int length = _msize(arr) / sizeof(int); // 42!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как так то ????

Comment: И как быть?????

Comment: @korch использовать коллекции - vector<int>. это "правильные" динамические массивы, у них можно узнать размер

Comment: Разве контейнер не работает на основе динамического массива? Или они там отдельно размер держат?

Comment: @korch они держат его внутри, но при этом запоминают размер, который был использован при создании.

Comment: Да, я это и имел в виду. Печально, ну ладно, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @korch чуть дополнил ответ - в некоторых реализациях узнать размер можно. но я бы все равно посоветовал vector.

Comment: А какой тип данных возвращает метод size()?

Comment: @korch size_type. это или unsigned int или unsigned long long.